# MS Access Update Query Not Updateable

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update a Table (CM_WCRoll) with calculated data from a Totals query (CM_qryLabor6...). I only need the query in order to read in the data, as data will only be written to the table which is editable. However the Update query will not run with the un-updateable query joined to my table.

```
UPDATE (PM_qryBOM_LvlX_nochild INNER JOIN (CM_qryLabor6_parentunion_sum_PROD INNER JOIN CM_WCRoll ON (CM_qryLabor6_parentunion_sum_PROD.PartID = CM_WCRoll.PartID) AND (CM_qryLabor6_parentunion_sum_PROD.WC_ID = CM_WCRoll.WC_ID)) ON PM_qryBOM_LvlX_nochild.PartID = CM_qryLabor6_parentunion_sum_PROD.PartID) SET CM_WCRoll.SumOfHrs = [CM_qryLabor6_parentunion_sum_PROD].[SumOfHrs];
```

What is the most efficient way to accomplish updating the table using the data from the query? Is a make-table the only way?

Comment: *Is a make-table the only way?* -- I'd say yes. Or an append query. http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up pasting the read only query data to a new make-table, and then used an update query to transfer the data from the make-table to my target table. It is working as expected and seems to be the fastest running approach as opposed to using DLookUp which takes some time to run.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a `DLookUp` with subquery `IN()` clause. Since the following (short-hand) original query is matching the *CM_WCRoll* table to *CM_* query and only uses *PM_* query for a lookup, run `DLookUp` for value assignment and subquery for lookup match.

Original Query

```
UPDATE (PM_qryBOM_LvlX_nochild p
INNER JOIN (CM_qryLabor6_parentunion_sum_PROD c
INNER JOIN CM_WCRoll t ON (c.PartID = t.PartID) AND (c.WC_ID = t.WC_ID)) 
     ON p.PartID = c.PartID) 
SET t.SumOfHrs = c.[SumOfHrs];
```

Adjusted Query

```
UPDATE CM_WCRoll t
SET t.SumOfHrs = DLookUp("SumOfHrs", "CM_qryLabor6_parentunion_sum_PROD", 
                         "PartID = " & t.PartID & " AND WC_ID = " &  t.WC_ID)
WHERE t.PartID IN
 (SELECT PartID FROM PM_qryBOM_LvlX_nochild);
```